# Why will extra fields in my Rails form not save to the database table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have my form

```
<% form_tag users_path, :id => 'registrationForm' do %>
  <div class="formElement">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
    <input name="user[email]" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="formElement">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="user[password]" type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="formElement">
    <label for="passwordConfirmation">Re-Enter Password</label>
    <input id="passwordConfirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" type="password">
  </div>

  <div class="formElement right">
    <input name="commit" value="Create" type="submit">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and then my controller method to process this which contains

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.save do |result|
  ...
end
```

This works fine. However, if I add 'first_name' and 'last_name' fields to my database table and add

```
<div class="formElement">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input id="firstName" name="user[first_name]" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="formElement">
  <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input id="lastName" name="user[last_name]" type="text" />
</div>
```

to my form, I get

> Mysql::Error: Column 'last_name'
>   cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users`
>   (`salt`, `ship_address_id`,
>   `created_at`, `single_access_token`,
>   `last_request_at`, `bill_address_id`,
>   `crypted_password`,
>   `remember_token_expires_at`,
>   `updated_at`, `perishable_token`,
>   `api_key`, `failed_login_count`,
>   `current_login_ip`,
>   `openid_identifier`,
>   `current_login_at`, `last_name`,
>   `remember_token`, `persistence_token`,
>   `login_count`, `last_login_ip`,
>   `last_login_at`, `login`, `email`,
>   `first_name`)
>   VALUES('gPa4FNsPHbfxLz1FTZJ8', NULL,
>   '2010-11-03 18:07:24',
>   'INl0QTDduoCKSdLLXEqb', '2010-11-03
>   18:07:24', NULL,
>   '900d7300768651e4814ca16b1dd39b85e8111c92a63d366c82e3f1d501dc7b85efc060bc2032e55e4405fe33b0883b0ad586fe47e99261b046a34a8b9d785333',
>   NULL, '2010-11-03 18:07:24',
>   'r8YSPUfKsmbIIJryvz5C', NULL, 0,
>   '127.0.0.1', NULL, '2010-11-03
>   18:07:24', NULL, NULL,
>   'd4fe33e9c1bde5e2468d74d3dc1de28089f565d7e0d39584690452547be6d3bbf529e9ac118575529f34e377cce315697538c64b19f799e386d6977a8f37912e',
>   1, NULL, NULL, 'testuser3@test.com',
>   'testuser3@test.com', NULL)

Here's the parameters the error page says were passed:

> {"commit"=>"Create",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"tFpn+DGMU3VfeaSrc5ckVoVCxfy76Xm0Mqf8Jx8JEFs=",
>   "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"test",
>   "last_name"=>"User3",
>   "password"=>"test",
>   "first_name"=>"Test3",
>   "email"=>"testuser3@test.com"}}

Any ideas why I get this MySQL error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) or [`attr_protected`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected) in your `User` model to guard against mass-assignment exploits?

Comment: attr_accessible was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you got it sorted out.